# Public folder deleted after using a migration command in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Something weird happened. I used the command `migrate:refresh` and after that I could not access my site anymore. I got the apache screen "error 403". After a few minutes I checked the `laravel_project/public` and everything there was gone.

I uploaded the public folder again and everything works fine. But this is just too weird and I am afraid that it will happen again. Anyone knows how did this happen? It could have been something else but it is weird that it happened in the moment that I use `php artisan migrate:refresh`.

Comment: weird stuff going on on your server, as well as weird question.

Comment: Is there anything in the `down` methods of your migrations that would cause this?